# Выпадающее меню для мобильного, hover - как работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, на десктопе меню открывается при наведении мышкой (css :hover), на мобильном устройстве делаю так, чтобы открывалось при клике.

> Проблема воспроизводится **при открытом** Chrome "Device toolbar" - режим разработки для мобильных.

Собственно проблема: при первом клике менюшка не открывается, далее все работает хорошо (то есть чтобы открыть выпадающее меню надо кликнуть 2 раза). Хотя на момент загрузки ДОМ выпадающий `ul` скрыт, он не открывается, словно срабатывает эффект `ховер` - меню показывается - и тут же jqury перехватывает, то что он видим и делает его невидимым. **Как убрать первый двойной клик?**

Если же убрать этот кусочек кода, то все прекрасно работает, но тогда на десктопе ховер не пашет.

```
ul li.menuparent:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**Сам код:**

```js
$(function() {

  console.log('Загрузка ДОМ: ' + $('#f ul').css('visibility'));

  $('li.menuparent > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Клик: ' + $('#f ul').css('visibility'));

    if ($('#f ul').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
      $('#f ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
      console.log('Обработка: скрыт, делаем видимым');
    } else {
      $('#f ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      console.log('Обработка: видим, делаем скрытым');

    }


    console.log('Конец клика: ' + $('#f ul').css('visibility'));
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul#f > li {
  background-color: #ddd;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li.menuparent:hover > ul {
  background: #c2c2c4 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 14px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<ul id="f">
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuparent">
    <a href="">Пункт 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: попробуйте поменять условие - сделайте наоборот, от противного : если показано, то скрыть, если нет, то показать

Comment: @lexxl все то же самое.

Comment: мне кажется лучше использовать toggleClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неохота переделывать видимость подменю с `visibility` в `display: none/block` готового модуля движка. В общем пободался и решил так, просто добавил `mouseover`:

```
$('li.menuparent > a').on('click mouseover', function(e) {}
```

либо сразу после загрузки дом присвоением меню hidden, и этот вариант наиболее подходящий, так как в первом варианте оба события происходят одновременно и перекрывают друг друга.

```
var submenu = ...
submenu.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```